# Estimating number of terms for partial fourier sum to minimize error

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> A function is define as 
>   $$
> f(t) = \begin{cases}
> 0 & \text{ if } \pi<x\le -1 \\ 
> x^2 & \text{ if } -1<x<1 \\ 
> 0 & \text{ if } 1\le x < \pi 
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find the number of $N$ such that $|S_n - f(x)|<\epsilon = 0.1$.

On it's solution, it begins with 
$$N \ge \frac{\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f'(x)|}{\pi \epsilon ^2 }$$
The paper is written in Danish, I can't understand why it begins with it. My best guess was to being with finding the coefficients (which I calculated) which is 
$$\epsilon  = \left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n \right| \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \left | \frac{2 \left(\left(n^2-2\right) \sin (n)+2 n \cos (n)\right)}{n^3}\right|\le  2\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{n^2 + 2n-2}{n^3}$$

And approximate the series and find the value of $N$ but it diverges. Can anyone point out to textbook which formula is used or what options do I have?